# How do I solve this Nvidia driver download error?

Tags: unity, 11.10, drivers, upgrade, nvidia

I can't enable or download any Nvidia drivers. In the image below, you can see I am offered four options. Selecting to enable any of them results in the error message shown:

[image: nvidia error]

Here's some of what is in /var/log/jockey.log:

```
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'usb:v0557p2221d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic03isc01ip02')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027B8sv00001043sd00008179bc06sc01i00')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'platform:reg-dummy')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'serio:ty01pr00id00ex00')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'usb:v046Dp08D9d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic01isc02ip00')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'pci:v00008086d000027C0sv00001043sd00008179bc01sc01i8f')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,5,kramlsfw2,')
2011-10-15 03:01:10,300 DEBUG: querying driver db <jockey.detection.OpenPrintingDriverDB instance at 0xb69126cc> about HardwareID('
modalias', 'acpi:PNP0103:')
2011-10-15 03:01:20,475 WARNING: modinfo for module nvidia_current_updates failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module nvidia_cur
rent_updates

2011-10-15 03:01:20,475 WARNING: /sys/module/nvidia_current_updates/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind nvidia_current_updates dr
iver
2011-10-15 03:01:42,270 DEBUG: Shutting down
```

I have a dual monitor set up, but because of this problem, I can only get one monitor to work.

How do I make it so I can actually use one of the Nvidia drivers and have complete graphics ability?

**Update:** If I run nvidia-config and generate an xorg.conf file, then my system won't boot.

**Update 2:** This problem can also occur on Ubuntu 12.04. Luckily, the provided solution also works there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution. Here's exactly how I did it. If you have a similar issue, your results may vary.

1. Go into Synaptic and completely remove all Nvidia related packages, plus Jockey. Make sure to "completely remove", not just uninstall.
2. Re-install ***only*** jockey-common, jockey-gtk, nvidia-common, nvidia-current, and nvidia-settings. If it tries to auto-select any other packages, unmark them. Seriously.
3. This is critical: After Synaptic has installed the selected packages, **reboot** once. Not rebooting at this point will cause failure later. At least, it did for me.
4. After rebooting, open System Settings->Additional Drivers. At this point, I saw different options than the screenshot in my original question. I went with the one marked "Recommended". Select activate, and reboot again.
5. After rebooting, you might not see much change. For me, I wanted to enable dual monitors but at this point only one monitor was on. Open up Nvidia-settings, and the second monitor is now recognized. Enable and configure as you see fit.

My graphics now seem to be working as they should.

I hope this information helps others with similar problems.

Also, this is how my restricted drivers interface now looks:

[image: nvidia-working]

Comment: Very detailed +1 Keep on going!

Comment: Had similar problem. Used `apt-get purge <package(s)>` to wipe out all settings of packages being removed.

Comment: Works like a charm, on 12.04.3 here. One thing to add, though - you're saying "If it tries to auto-select any other packages, unmark them. Seriously.". However, selecting nvidia-current and / or nvidia-settings also automatically selects nvidia-304 and nvidia-settings-304. Unselecting any of these also deselects the former packages (which are required). Also, these two packages don't cause any problems. Seriously :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Package Manager, search for the "nvidia-current" package and install it. That's basically what's the Additional Drivers program is doing.

Comment: Did it work in a previous release? (assuming you've upgraded) What video card do you have?

Comment: Before trying the longer solution suggested by Dave M.G., I tried this one and it wokred :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After running apt-get update my second monitor would not work. So I searched for a while and finally I ran across this post. The solution worked for me as well except I didn't have to do anything after the reboot. I had followed exact instructions until then though. The only other thing I would like to add is in the instructions it just says remove all nvidia packages and some newbies (That's not a bad word. We all were new at some point) may not know how to do that so I will include the command here. It's `sudo apt-get remove nvidia*` that should remove all instances for you. Don't forget the asterisk after nvidia. the same goes for removing jockey. Use the same command and put "jockey*" where nvidia* was. I know this seems trivial to some, but there was a time when I needed exact instruction and sometimes that still didn't work. Anyways thanks for the post! It helped me out a ton!